# Webclient c# get cookie from url in loop

Tags: c#, cookies, webclient

I'm trying to get cookie-response from a website.

For example each time I visit google.com I would like to retrieve new cookie values, is this possible? Below I'll have a code using webbrowser to retrieve cookies :

```
var cookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(webBrowser3.Url,false);
```

I tried httpwebrequest also using codes I found on this site, but I can not get new cookie-values from the website.

All help would be appreciated

Regards,
dennis

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found a working method over here but i can not put this code in a loop.

```
var StringURL = "http://www.google.com";
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        request = HttpWebRequest.Create(StringURL) as HttpWebRequest;
        HttpWebResponse TheRespone = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        String setCookieHeader = TheRespone.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

        textBox18.Text = TheRespone.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];
```

If i put this code into my application, which runs in a loop the application get stuck. When I put this code on a button, I can push button once and it prints out the cookie perfect, but when I hit the button again the app will get stuck also. So if there is anyone with a solution for this please be so kind to explain what I'm doing wrong.